# textarea single line issue Unable to hit enter

Tags: html, css

I have an issue regarding text area displaying single line mode not accept enter for break line. 
any suggestion regarding this

```html
<textarea autocomplete="OFF" class="form-control col-xs-12 multi-line valid" cols="22" id="description" name="description" rows="5" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 129px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: not working at my side..

Comment: I can't see where you defined `single line mode`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the reason for this behaviour of TextArea.

There is nothing special. There was a code to prevents the "Enter" key for this TextArea at runtime in js file. I was not able to find out that implementation and stucking in the TeatArea.

Thanks to all of you for your valuable replies!!